# mysql query, different performance between = and IN

Tags: mysql, sql

why there is this difference of time execution between these two queries even if they retrieve the same amount of rows from the same table?

```
select cognome, nome, lingua, count(*)
from archivio.utente
where cognome in ('rossi','pecchia','pirono')
group by cognome, nome, lingua;
```

…
…

```
…
| Rossi                | Mario   | it     |        1 |
| Pironi               | Luigi   | it     |        1 |
| Pecchia              | Fabio   | it     |        1 |
+----------------------+---------+--------+----------+
```

779 rows in set (0.03 sec)

```
select cognome, nome, lingua, count(*)
from archivio.utente
where nome='corrado'
group by cognome, nome, lingua;
```

…
…
…

```
| Rossi                | Mario   | it     |        1 |
| Pironi               | Luigi   | it     |        1 |
| Pecchia              | Fabio   | it     |        1 |
+----------------------+---------+--------+----------+
```

737 rows in set (0.47 sec)

Comment: Perhaps the second is run on a cold cache (i.e. it was run first).  To compare timings, you need to run queries multiple times and be careful about whether the data has already been read into memory.

Comment: You're testing two different columns. Maybe `cognome` is indexed and `name` isn't?

Comment: They do not "retrieve the same amount of rows"; 779 vs 737.

Comment: In addition to the notes from Gordon, very likely that the queries have different execution plans due to the difference in the predicates (i.e. conditions in the WHERE clause). We use `EXPLAIN` to have MySQL show us the query execution plan. Queries with different execution plans often exhibit differences in performance. (There's no difference between `(a=b OR a=c)` and `a IN (b,c)`.  The performance difference isn't due to the `=` and `IN` operators; what's different is the conditions that are being checked.

Comment: This is like asking why is it so easy to find persons by their last name in a telephone book, but so slow to find persons by their first name. It's just two different searches on different columns. It's likely that tadman is right about the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

from mysql documentation :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types

when we use in

Only rows that are in a given range are retrieved, using an index to select the rows. 
The key column in the output row indicates which index is used.

when we use =

A full table scan is done for each combination of rows

So in one case all lines are retrieved and compared, in another case just a range.

Comment: You should edit the question instead of posting the answer.